# Swift 3 - using DispatchGroup() to wait for completion for each URL session?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swift3, synchronous

Hi so I have this problem where I have an array filled with string (for example: [dog,cat,girraffe,cow]) and I am to use this id to make an API call to some website to get the image from that site. I need the result to be in same order as the array.

For this example I need the output to be like this if i print both arrays it should be like this:
**theString - dog, cat, girraffe, cow**

**age - 5, 10, 20, 5  <-- the ordering corresponds to the animal**

but instead, I get the age outputs like:
**age - 5, 20, 10, 5 OR**

**age - 10, 20, 5, 5 etc.**

I pretty much have to role the dice until i get the output to be in order.

since each API call is async, the ordering is always random when it comes to the age. I have been stuck on this issue for days now, not quite sure how to go about it..

example code:

```
let theString = ["dog", "cat", "girraffe", "cow"]
var age = Array<Int>() // to store the ages of the animal in order



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     //make the call 4 times
    for each in theString{
      doAPICall(name:each)
      print(age)//the output is not in order 
    }


}


func doAPICall(name: String){

  let animal = name
  let urlString:String = "https://somewebsite.com/api/"+ animal

    let url = URL(string: urlString)!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error!.localizedDescription)

        } else{
            do{

                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                let age = parsedData["age"] as! Int
                self.age.append(age) //appends the age to the array

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }//end else

    })
    task.resume()
}
```

In short, I need some way to tell the for loop or the async call to wait until the previous one is complete before moving onto the next

Comment: You can use completion block

Comment: @bhupatBheda can you elaborate a little on that? I did look into completion block and saw some examples on here, but I could not fully understand the implementation. I'm fairly new to Swift

Comment: Can you tell me your purpose what you exactly trying to do ?

Comment: So now you are calling the api and want to response in same order ?

Comment: I basically have a tableview that displays a match history of a video game.  and I need the data to be stored in order from most recent match. each match has a corresponding icon. To get that icon I need to make an API call with the matchID as the input, and it will give me the string so I can store it in a variable.  But obviously in order for me to print out the icon in order, I must store it in the same order as my matchID array. Which it does not, since asynchronous call can finish whenever.   i just used animals to simplify the problem.

Comment: yes, that is right. sorry for the confusion. The process of getting the datas are very tedious, so I needed to simplify my process for the sake of understanding

Comment: Ok so you need to call api with completion block & synchrounus mode

Comment: could you reference me to something I can look at or some tutorial? or how would you do it to my simplified example?

Comment: I put my answer please check it i hope it might be helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to initialise `age` with `nil` values first:

```
var age = [Int?](repeating: nil, count: theString.count)
```

Then, after each call completes, set the value at the right index to the result you got.

```
    } else{
        do{

            let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
            let age = parsedData["age"] as! Int

            // Note these lines!
            if let index = theString.index(of: animal) {
                self.age[index] = age
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }//end else
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this!

```
let theString = ["dog", "cat", "girraffe", "cow"]
var age = Array<Int>() // to store the ages of the animal in order

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     //make the call 4 times
    for each in theString{
      doAPICall(animal: each,completion: { (responseArray,error) -> () in
           let age = responseArray["age"] as! Int
           if let index = theString.index(of: each) {
            self.age[index] = age
          }
        })
      print(age)//the output is in order 
    }
}
func doAPICall(animal: String,completion:@escaping (_ responsedata:NSDictionary?_ error:NSError?) -> Void){

  let Baseurl = "https://somewebsite.com/api/"+ animal
  let RequestUrl = URL(string: Baseurl)
  let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: RequestUrl!)
  let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
  let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

  guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print("error=\(error?.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
            if httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }
        }
        do {
            let ResponseDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: .allowFragments) as! as! NSDictionary?
            completion(ResponseDictionary,nil)
            semaphore.signal()
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Details of JSON parsing error:\n \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(nil,error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
}
```

Comment: There is a warning on semaphore.wait -  "Result of call to 'wait(timeout:)' is unused.  how are we using the .wait?

Comment: use like this _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture) then it will not give any warning

Comment: The code directly related to `URLSession` and `JSONSerialization` is a good deal worse than the code in the question.

Comment: okay I managed to get it working with a couple tweaks from your solution.  And as expected, my tableview loaded all the data at once, instead of one at a time (which could obviously cause problems with large data set, but that's irrelevant to this topic).   What is the httpStatus check for? that's not necessary is it? if I know that my URL will give me an object for certain?